# Replacing a whole equation in beamer

Tags: beamer, presentations

I want an equation to be replaced by another in one click in a beamer presentation. How to implement that?

I was trying it by writing two exactly same consequent frames where the latter frame had old equation replaced by the new one! I understand it's not a good way at all and there should be something in-built that I don't know.

Comment: Look at the concepts of overlays in the Beamer manual. Sounds like exactly what you want.

Comment: @William'Ike'Eisenhauer Seems that was the answer. Could you turn your comment into an answer (best with a little bit of explanation and a small example to not just have a link to the manual)?

Answer (score 12):

Use the overlay specifications, as indicated in the beamer manual.

The `\only` directive is what you need in this case. It directs beamer to render that segment for a specific slide, if you put two of them, one right after the other, you achieve the effect you want. For example:

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usetheme{Madrid} 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Example of RSM}
\begin{block}{Find Stationary Point}
\begin{align*}
  \only<1>{\frac{\partial \hat{y}}{\partial w_1} &= 2.316 &- 3.775w_2 &- 7.574w_1 &&= 0 \\}
  \only<2>{\frac{\partial \hat{y}}{\partial w_2} &= 0&- 3.775w_1 &&-10.126w_2 &= 0 \\}
\end{align*}
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```